# How do I add an event after I removed all events in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How do I add an event after all events have been removed? What I trying to do is set it up so that when you click on the jQuery Datepicker, it removes all events, and adds only from the selected month.

Here is my code:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = new Date(dateText);
        calendar
            .fullCalendar('gotoDate', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())
            .fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay')
            .fullCalendar('removeEvents');

        Events.getEvents({
            year: date.getFullYear(),
            month: date.getMonth() + 1
        },function(events) {
            $(events).each(function(index,event) {
                console.log(event)
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',event,true);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

If I call **fullCalendar('removeEvents')**, everything works great except that duplicate events, but if I add **removeEvents**, it removes all events, but does not add the other...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out.

Only need to

change calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',event,true);

into

calendar.fullCalendar('**addEventSource**',**events**);

Note that, you can not add 1 event, you need to add all in one time. In my example **events** is array where holding all events.